# Why does my console say Truffle(ganache) instead of Truffle(develop)

Tags: blockchain, solidity, truffle, decentralized-applications

I'm trying to follow a truffle tutorial and getting stuck.  I have made a basic contract and migration script and done the truffle compile and truffle migrate.

After this in the tutorials, the command line says "truffle(develop)" whereas mine says "truffle(ganache)". I'm not able to actually run the rest of the tutorial and think this may be why...

Thank you!

Comment: Have you configured ganache with the truffle develop?

Answer (score 1):

What the command line says is dependent on the network which you're on.
In the root folder of your project there must be a file named `truffle-config.js` (or `truffle.js` for Windows). This file, among others, contains networks definitions that you may use. To achieve what you want, you may uncomment the lines that define the `development` network, save the file and then run `truffle develop`. Note that `truffle develop` may run without the need of `ganache`. To connect to ganache, you can figure out the port that ganache uses (for example ganache-cli uses 8545) and use that port in the development definition in the file `truffle-config.js`.

If for some reason you have messed up the `truffle-config.js` file, you may re-initiate a truffle project (maybe to a new folder location and then copy your contract & migration files there) with `truffle init`.